# Default Pages in DNN wont load as I deleted the 404 Error page

Tags: dotnetnuke, dnn9

I was trying to solve a problem by deleting a 404 Error page in DNN (Recycle Bin was also cleaned) so that I can create a completely new page.

When I try to go back to Site Settings > Site Behavior > Default Pages, it fails to load and gives a wrong Internet Connection message which is caused by DNN not finding the default 404 Error page anymore.

[image]

**UPDATE**

I did try to RUN the following to set the 404 Error Page to a default value, but it still seems broken.

```
Update [dbo].[PortalLocalization] set Custom404TabID = NULL
```

I get the following error in the Console when trying to load Default Pages. It says the portal ID is undefined, but I checked and it is defined in PortalLocalization.

```
HTTP500: SERVER ERROR - The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

(XHR)GET - https://www.ourwebsite.co.za/API/PersonaBar/SiteSettings/GetDefaultPagesSettings?portalId=undefined&cultureCode=en-US
```

Comment: Tried to reproduce the problem by deleting the 404 page from DNN 9.2.2, but everything worked fine after that without the 404 page. The settings were also available.

Comment: Hmmm, That is strange. We are still running on DNN 9.01.01 as we cannot upgrade our DNN yet due to modules which have to be updated for Deprecated JQuery functions in the skin. I will try to re-create the problem in DNN 9.2.2, perhaps they fixed a bug.